# Assigning Key vault secret to pipeline variable

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I have linked Azure key vault via Variable group in release pipeline:
[image]

Now the application is passing environment variable SQL_Login. In KeyVault since underscore isnt allowed we have named the variable as SQLServerLogin.
Under Pipeline variables, I assigned it like the below:
[image]
But it didnt take the value.
I tried giving Key vault secret in []. Still it didnt solve the issue.
How will I assign Keyvault secret to variable name SQL_Login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, when you use secret variable SQLServerLogin  to set the variable SQL_Login, it will not pass the value to new variable.

To use the secret variable in Azure Pipeline, you need to explicitly map secret variables in Agent Job.

If you are using PowerShell/Bash, you can directly set the environment variable.

```
- powershell: |
   echo $(SQL_Login)
   
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
  env:
    SQL_Login: $(SQLServerLogin)
```

If you want to set the Pipeline variable, you can use logging command.

Example:

```
- powershell: |

   
   echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SQL_Login]$env:SQL_Login"
   
 
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
  env:
    SQL_Login: $(SQLServerLogin)
```

Then you can use the variable:`$(SQL_Login)` in the next tasks.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Set secret variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables)

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: We have already set all the stages and tasks and then integrating Key Vault.And we are not using YAMl. Its classic CD pipeline. Each stage has 10+ powershell tasks. Its hectic job to update the same secrets for each task. Thats why thought of setting them under pipeline variable section. Is there a quicker way to achieve this?

Comment: I am afraid that there is no other method can explicitly map secret variables. I suggest that you can explicitly map secret variables and set the pipeline variable: `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SQL_Login]$env:SQL_Login"`   Then you can directly use the variable `$(SQL_Login)` in the next tasks. You can add the PowerShell task at the top of the job. In this case, you only need to set the variable once

Comment: okay let me try that and get back you on this

Comment: I have used echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SQL_Login]$env:SQLServerLogin". SQLServerLogin is the variable from Keyvault but it prints the value as SQLServerLogin. not sure if I understood the concept here. I have linked Key vault in Variable groups as well in the pipeline

Comment: You need to set the environment variable in Pipeline task. Then `SQL_Login: $(SQLServerLogin)`. Then the secret key value will pass to PowerShell  env variable `$env:SQL_Login`. Then you can set the pipeline variable with the command.

Comment: okay checking the same

Comment: Do you mean the same settings still have the same issue? If yes, can u update some screenshot about how you use the variable? for example some command or script

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I didnt update the Environment variable section earlier in the new task added for assigning secrets . It did work and really saved a lot of time!!!! Thank you so much for this :)

Comment: Glad to know that it can work! My pleasure